# Android: How to increase Accelerometer Sampling Rate?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, accelerometer, sampling

I am currently using Java API to get accelerometer values in 5Hz, which is below my requirements. I want to achieve at least 50Hz. Is there any way to increase the sampling rate of accelerometer?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the maximun sampling rate is diferent between diferent android phones. What i think you can do is setup the sensormanager to update the data as fast as it can, take a look of the constant [SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST) from the documentation.

regards.

Answer (score 0):

> The param **SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST**
>   indicates to android to poll for data
>   as fast as it can.

The sampling-rate of the accelerometer is determined by the driver is different from the polling rate which is configurable in Android.

There are no APIs for the java/C apps to control the internal sampling-rate. This is because the kernel-drivers do NOT expose any APIs to control the h/w sampling-rate as it is best left to the designers of the device to set this.

You can poll for the accel-data as often as you need it. Check in the source (if you have access) or with the ODM/OEM for details of the accelerometer's internal sampling rate.

Answer (score -1):

Yse the microphone. If you vibrate the phone in 50 Hz the mic will get it.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the tip! Mic will do it just fine :)

Comment: Ummm.. no - AudioTrack has ~100ms buffer :(

Comment: I don't get it; why is the audio buffer stopping you in doing this.