# Android accelerometer: Sampling Rate?

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, sampling, rate

I want to

[1] Increase Sampling Rate of my phone's accelerometer. 
   (SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST gives max. **about** 100Hz on Xperia/ 180Hz on Nexus4,
    I want delay to be about 1ms or less for my work.

[2] If [1] not possible **can i make Rate constant**.

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,10000);//10000 in microsec
```

Above code **doesn't** give me 10ms delay. I know it's only a suggestion to Android.

I know These accelerometers inside phones are capable of giving much smaller delay. It's mentioned in their datasheets. So is their any method or driver/ADC programming to do [1] or [2]. 
I'm using ADT tools. Any other tool to do this?

P.S: I've read

[Android: How to increase Accelerometer Sampling Rate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224223/android-how-to-increase-accelerometer-sampling-rate)

[Impossibility to change the rate of the accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358862/impossibility-to-change-the-rate-of-the-accelerometer)

Answer (score 7):

From [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-monitor) :

> The data delay (or sampling rate) controls the interval at which
>   sensor events are sent to your application via the onSensorChanged()
>   callback method. The default data delay is suitable for monitoring
>   typical screen orientation changes and uses a delay of 200,000
>   microseconds. You can specify other data delays, such as
>   SENSOR_DELAY_GAME (20,000 microsecond delay), SENSOR_DELAY_UI (60,000
>   microsecond delay), or SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST (0 microsecond delay). **As
>   of Android 3.0 (API Level 11) you can also specify the delay as an
>   absolute value (in microseconds).**

But you should know the absolute value you specify in microseconds is only a *suggestion* to Android.

Comment: I know this but I want a perfect constant sampling rate.

Answer (score 4):

From my experience, here's what you can do. Let's start with the easiest:

[2] [in short] You cannot have a perfect **accuracy** (interval between readings) on (this) Android.

[2] [in long] You need to define *perfect*; that is, you have to define your **precision**. Note, this will never be a perfect 0; it never is, not even in the most critical applications imaginable. From my experience, on android, this can be even a full blown 100 ms.

[1] If your application is not critical, i.e. you just want to analyze some historical data you can try the following: save each reading with its timestamp; then, *interpolate* at a fixed interval; you will have a perfect time distribution but also an estimation.

Good luck, and ask if something is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/dantasse/AccelerometerTest - here you can download a source code for an app that testes your real sampling rate. I don't think you can achieve in practice 100Hz or more... I'm working right now on testing sampling rates. 
So the answer for now is not- you cant achieve a 1 millisecond delay (even in theory).